# Is haystack supposed to return a model object or just pieces of it?

Tags: python, django, django-haystack

I am following tutorials that use haystack, and their view templates are set up like this

```
{% for result in results %}

    {% with post=result.object %}

    <h4><a href="{{ post.get_absolute_url }}">{{ result.title }}</a></h4>
    {{ post.body|truncatewords:5 }}
    {% endwith %}
    {% empty %}
    <p>There are no results for your query.</p>
{% endfor %}
```

This is the part that interests me

```
{% with post=result.object %}
```

and this

```
<h4><a href="{{ post.get_absolute_url }}">{{ result.title }}</a></h4>
```

typically from what I've read the syntax is

```
result.object.get_absolute_url
```

but he obviously did this

```
with post=result.object
```

to make his work without object

My thing is this; I don't have access to get_absolute_url. I don't have the actual object returned. Only pieces of it that are obtained using this

```
publish = indexes.DateTimeField(model_attr='publish')
title = indexes.CharField(model_attr='title')
body = indexes.CharField(model_attr='body')
```

Now with those, I can do this:

```
{% for result in results %}
    {% with post=result.object %}
    {{result.publish}}<br>
    {{result.title}}<br>
    {{result.body}}<br><hr>
    #......
```

but this is not the actual object just stripped off pieces how can I get the actual object so I can use

```
href="{{result.object.get_absolute_url}}"
```

instead of having to do this

```
slug = indexes.CharField(model_attr='slug')
```

then having to do this

```
href="{% url 'blog:post_detail' result.slug %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You *do* have the object, in `result.object`. You've used a `with` statement to assign that to `post`, but then you've ignored that variable completely.

Comment: thanks for the response. Lets disregard the assignment for a minute because that's his code. If I have the object then why cant I do this result.object.get_absolute_url. If I try and use that for an href and inspect the element, the href is blank. the only thing that gets returned are things that I have done this to title = indexes.CharField(model_attr='title')
other than that it wont return the object. I have followed this tutorial verbatim. Also this is my second time using haystack and I only seem to  be able to use 'result.title' not 'result.object.title'